# Get websites title in python for bitcoin exchange rate

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, bitcoin

so iv'e been working on a bitcoin mining rig and i have a raspberry pi model B as a rig manager system. I've bought a small 2x16 display and i want to display the bitcoin exchange rate. How do i do that ? i know how to display the data on the screen buy i dont know how to get the exchange rate to the pi ... i thought about getting it from a `<title>` of a web site like:

> http://preev.com/

or:

```
http://www.bitcoinexchangerate.org/
```

where in both the `<title>` of the web site are the refreshing exchange rate of bitcoin in USD.

is that possible ?
and if not, how can i do that ?

thanks ahead !

EDIT !
heres what i have till now:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#coding:utf-8

from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
from mechanize import Browser

#This retrieves the webpage content
br = Browser()
res = br.open("https://www.google.com/")
data = res.get_data() 

#This parses the content
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
title = soup.find('title')

#This outputs the content :)
print title.renderContents()
```

but it gives out a syntax eror.
what libraries should be imported for that ?

Comment: Check out http://bitcoincharts.com/about/markets-api/, they have an api that spits out JSON which you can contact using the curl (i think) library, then it's just a matter of parsing the json for what you want.

Comment: Are you on Python 3? If so, you must write `print(title.renderContents())`, not `print title.renderContents()`. Furthermore, the Beautiful Soup module is called `bs4`, not `BeautifulSoup`.

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.bitcoinexchangerate.org/') 
soup = BeautifulSoup(response)
print soup.title.string
```

Comment: it returns: invalid syntax and marks the word soup in last line

Comment: Are you sure you installed BeautifulSoup correctly ? Have you installed it using pip ? What is your python version ?